# Replacing defined constant by an integer value in function with matrices

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I would like to modify the N-Queens backtracking algorithm by getting the size of the board (N) from the standard input instead of defining N as a constant. 
However, I can't match the types at the functions. Should I define some kind of global maximum constant and then work with n?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool safe(int N, char mat[][N], int v, int k)
{
    int i, j; 
    for (i = 0; i < v; i++) 
        if (mat[i][k] == 'Q')
            return false;
    for (i = v, j = k; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--) 
        if (mat[i][j] == 'Q')
            return false;

    for (i = v, j = k; i >= 0 && j < N; i--, j++) 
        if (mat[i][j] == 'Q')
            return false;

    return true;
}

void backtrack(int N, char mat[][N], int v)
{
    if (v == N)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                cout << mat[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;

        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (safe(N, mat, v, i))
        {
            mat[v][i] = 'Q';
            backtrack(N, mat, v + 1);
            mat[v][i] = '-';
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N; 
    cin >> N;
    char mat[N][N];
    memset(mat, '-', sizeof mat);

    backtrack(N,mat, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`char mat[N][N];` is a Variable Length Array (VLA) which is a non standard extension of some c++ compilers that you should avoid using. If you need run-time allocated memory, consider using a `std::vector`:

```
int N{};
std::cin >> N;
std::vector<std::vector<char>> mat(N, std::vector<char>(N, '-'));
```

will do what you want. You can then pass this to any function using:

```
void foo(const std::vector<std::vector<char>>& mat); // for read-only
void foo(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& mat); // for read-write
```

*Note: this is potentially less effeccient depending on how memory is allocated. If you need your memory to line up all together, use a 1D vector and access function to get index for you.*